# What is the purpose of `new Schema` when creating schemas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have seen two different syntaxes when using Mongoose.  One uses `new Schema` to create a model why the other does not ...

**Syntax 1**

```
let schema = new Schema({ 
    // ... snip
});
```

**Syntax 2**

```
let schema = { // ... snip }
```

Both are used to create a model as follows:

```
const Class = mongoose.model(name, schema);
```

Comment: It's simply leveraging JavaScript's two forms of syntax for object instantiation. #1 is explicit. #2 is implicit.

Comment: Also how is second one used? Perhaps =>  `let schema = new Schema(schema_1)`?

Comment: @Scott - It is also using the Schema constructor which is part of the Mongoose library.

Comment: @chris I thought that was obvious.

Comment: So is there a right way to do it or is it just a matter of preference?  I would assume the Schema constructor is doing something ... but what ?  As a matter of diligence, should the source code be read to see what it does ?